# Concatenating ids with extension to keep multiple rows related to an entity in a single Column Family

Tags: java, database-design, key, primary-key

I am concatenating  two Integer ids through bitwise operations(as described below) to create a single primary key of type long. I wanted to know if this is a good practice. This would help me in keeping multiple rows of an entity in a single column family by appending different extensions to the entityId.
Are there better ways ? My Ids are of type Integer(4 bytes).

```
public static final long makeCompositeKey(int entityId, int extension){
    return (long)entityId << 32 | extension;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most databases come with a built-in way to create IDs automatically, and your app doesn't need to care about it.  I'm most familiar with Postgres, where I create a sequence for each table and use that for the `@Id` column, but I know that Oracle and MSSQL have their own way of accomplishing the same thing.

In general, however, each column in your database should store a single piece of information.  Taking two pieces of info and concatenating them together as you're suggesting goes against "proper" database design according to "book learning."  By which I mean: you should only do it if you have a very, very good reason for doing so (and even then, you should think two or three times about it before actually doing it.)  If you don't have a good reason for doing it, then don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design. It should be two different columns having composite constraint. You can have a another generated Unique ID for as a primary key.

Aside from the primary key, You can also create a composite index on two columns to speed up the queries if most queries will filter based on these two values.